# Is there a dataset for the optimum conditions (Temperature, humidity, light intensity, etc.) for plants growth?

Tags: botany, database

I'm a student working on an automated greenhouse. I wanted to add a database for the most commonly grown plants and the optimum conditions needed (I'm mainly looking for temperature, humidity, and light intensity) for the plants' growth. I have already found a dataset on Kaggle, but I was wondering if there are any datasets that include light intensity. Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: All the info is out there, but you need to search for the specific plants you're growing as their optimal growing conditions may vary widely. "Commonly grown plants" is a pretty broad category, not one-(x)-fits-all and varies widely by culture and purpose.

Comment: @Belal Bahaa Did you have any luck finding what you were looking for?

Comment: The best one I found was the one in Kaggle. Thankfully, I'm done with that project!